# AWS kinesis firehouse not able to connect to aws private api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to send AWS kinesis firehouse stream to invoke AWS private api gateway.

Flow as below::

Test data --> aws kinesis firehouse --> private api gateway --> private ec2 hosted service.

- I have setup VPC endpoint of type interface for AWS private api gateway
- configured Kinesis firehouse HTTP endpoint as https://{rest-api-id}-{vpce-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage}

But go the error as -

> Unable to connect to the destination endpoint. Contact the owner of the endpoint to resolve this issue.

What i am missing? Is it possible to call private api gateway request from aws kinesis firehouse?

Comment: I don't think you can invoke private http endpoints. Do you have any reference to docs which say you can do that?

Comment: one example private vpc aws lambda --> kinesis firehouse (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/vpc.html)

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed with AWS support just now (same flow - but my case: private API, private lambdas inside vpc, vpc endpoint with private DNS disabled):

> currently Kinesis Data Firehose does NOT support data delivery to HTTP
> endpoints in a VPC

and

> In order to deliver data using Firehose, configured HTTP endpoint
> destination should be publicly accessible.